# Using R functions in SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark

I want to use R for statistical analytic for Big Data. For that I want to use Spark as Big Data server. And using SparkR as bridging tool. My requirement is to use aggregate function and other functions of R for generating report like count of each category in a table. In SparkR textFile function returns RDD and I want to use it with R function. R function are available for data frame oor other data types of R. Is there any code sample or developer guide is available please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite new. Just in Feb 2015, DataBricks announced the support of DataFrame in Spark. https://databricks.com/blog/2015/02/17/introducing-dataframes-in-spark-for-large-scale-data-science.html.

The link I provided has code sample for Python, but such API exists in Python, Java, Scala, and R (in development via SparkR) acocording to the annoucement.

Comment: Thank you I found this link while searching for answer. I didn't read it fully this DataFrame is not same type of R. Let me check if I can write statement like table(dataframe$diabetes, dataframe$status) where diabetes and status are field in dataframe